# scipy and matlab fft results differ

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, fft

I am working with a large amount of data and am trying to use the fftpack in scipy to help me out. In Matlab, I have code that looks like:

```
val1 = fft(val1,fft_window_size);
```

where fft_window_size is 2^19.
This outputted:

```
val1
ans = -5.5162
ans = 4.5001 - 0.0263i
ans = -2.4261 + 0.0256i
ans = 0.8575 - 0.0233i
ans = -0.2189 + 0.0531i
```

For the first 5 indices of Val1.
In Python, I used:

```
val1=scipy.fftpack.fft(val1,fft_window_size)
```

where the fft_window_size was the same as listed above (2**19) and got completely different answers for the first 5 indices:

```
('val1', array([-7.6888 +0j, 5.2122 - 0.07556j,
-1.4928+0.02275j, 0.15854 +0.01481j, -0.07528+0.03379j]))
```

I've looked at as many examples as I could find and couldn't find a good answer as to why they are so vastly different. I checked val1 all the way up to this command and the two matched perfectly (with Python having more decimal places). I don't think this is a rounding issue, but I'm not sure what else to look at.

Any thoughts would be good.

Comment: How large is the input `val1`?  Do matlab and scipy agree with a very small example, such `fft([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 8)`?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser val1 has around 50,000 values in it. They appear to match when I ran the smaller array you suggested, so I would assume they matched for bigger arrays. Is this not always the case?

Comment: They *should* match.  What is the data type of the input?  In python, check `val1.dtype`, and in matlab, check `class(val1)`.  Also, the first value returned by `fft` is simply the sum of the values in the input, so it would be interesting to see `val1.sum()` in python and `sum(val1)` in matlab.

Comment: The reassignment `val1 = fft(val1,fft_window_size);` means I have to keep emphasizing the input `val1` vs. the output `val1`.  Could you use a different variable?  What you do in your actual code is your choice, but it would be simpler here if you didn't redefine `val1`.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser So I use val2 instead of val1, would that make a difference?
As for the types, matlab is called a double while python is 'complex128', but matlab still has complex values? 
The sum for matlab is `(-1.3144e-07 - 5.3776e-17i)` while for python it is `(-0.0021907+8.88178e-16j)` . Those seem pretty different.

Comment: *"So I use val2 instead of val1, would that make a difference?"*  Yes, that would make it easier to talk about the variables.  Thanks for checking the types--they are both using double precision.   Now, the sums that you show don't match the outputs in either the scipy or matlab FFT.  Double check that you are really using the same `val1` each time, and that they are the same in python and matlab.  You said "the two matched perfectly" up to the FFT, but clearly if those sums are different, they don't match perfectly.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Did you tell me to do the sums before or after the fft? Because I summed them after.

Comment: In Matlab, sum before fft is: -5.5162 -which is the same as the first index
In python, it's: -7.6888 -which also appears to be the first index
Also, I double checked the types (once I changed val1 to val2 as mentioned above) and val1's type is actually float64 when it goes into the fft while matlab's val1 is still a double. Does that make a difference?

Comment: Yes, sum the input, `val1`. :)   What have you done so far that convinced you the inputs matched perfectly?  I suggest you try to figure out why the sums are different in python and matlab.  Perhaps simply print some values from the beginning, middle and end of `val1`.  Use `format long` in matlab to see more digits.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I accidentally duplicated code elsewhere. I only found it out when you suggested to print sums throughout. Thank you very much for your help. :)